# How to remove an Existing Site Column from list?

Tags: site-column

I need to remove an Existing Site Column from a list.

This has already been answered here:
[How do you remove fields from a custom list in SharePoint that have been added via the 'Add from existing site columns' menu item?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-do-you-remove-fields-from-a-custom-list-in-sharepoint-that-have-been-added-v)

The problem is i don't understand how he is doing it? Is he using Powershell?

Answer (score 3):

That code is C# though the powershell isn't that different and would probably look pretty close to this :

```
$site = Get-SPSite "UrlToSiteCollection"
$web = $site.OpenWeb("/Url/To/Web/Containing/List")
$list = $web.Lists["CustomTest"]
$f = $list.Fields["Page Image"]
$f.Sealed = $false
$f.Update()
$list.Fields["Page Image"].Delete()
```

Comment: Just fixed a typo on a variable name

Comment: maybe a AllowUnsafeUpdates=true would be needed prior to chaning Web structure