# Remove existing Column from List

Tags: 2013, list, column

I know there are different questions and answers to this, but they are old or have a different approach.

I have added some existing site columns to a list via "Add from existing site columns". Now I want to remove some of them.

There is a way to do this [with Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65880/how-to-remove-an-existing-site-column-from-list), but I need a GUI to do this for other employees. They are not able to work with Powershell and if they do not remove old columns, the list management will get very clunky over the time, because of all those unused columns.

Comment: I am only familiar with SP2010, but with 2010 in the list settings you can click on the column and just click a "delete" button. Isn't there such an option in 2013? Or maybe I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: This Delete button is only visible at custom added elements, not the elements that were added from existing site columns.

Comment: Than that's different from 2010, because there it's also available for added existing site columns. Maybe someone with more 2013 experience passes by, sorry that I was of no help.